# How can I make the caption of each sub figure like

Tags: positioning, memoir, subfloats

I have 6 figures, two classes, and want them to be arranged as

```
Figure 1-C1    Figure 2-C2

(a)               (c)

Figure 3-C1    Figure 4-C2

(b)               (d)

Figure 5-C1    Figure 6-C2

(c)               (e)
```

Well, I just want to put each class of figures in one column and the caption of them is one followed by another. Not to number them in a horizontal direction.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}            % added on 19112013
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}  % added on 20112013 for tabular

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \subbottom[QMF 02DB2A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/qmf02db3a.jpg}\label{fig319:a}}    \quad
      \subbottom[IQ 02DB2A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/iq02db3a.jpg}\label{fig319:d}}\\

        \subbottom[QMF 04DB1A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/qmf04db1a.jpg}\label{fig319:b}}    \quad
      \subbottom[IQ 04DBA]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/iq04db1a.jpg}\label{fig319:e}}\\

        \subbottom[QMF 04DB3A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/qmf04db3a.jpg}\label{fig319:c}}    \quad
      \subbottom[IQ 04DB3A]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{chap3/iq04db3a.jpg}\label{fig319:f}}
    \caption{Temporary Caption}
    \label{fig319}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post a little and make it fully compilable (minimum working) example? Also please bear in mind that solvers don't have your figures, it would be wise to change names to figures used in the `mwe` package. That package we have for sure.

Comment: Why do you have two fig319:c labels? Presumably that is an error given they point to different jpg files and have different captions?

Comment: I modified the fig319:c, but it does not impact the caption order.

Comment: Sure, just that I thought it would probably throw up an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange the content inside a `tabular` or a `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newcommand{\tabstrut}{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7\baselineskip+6pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \subbottom[QMF 02DB2A\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\label{fig319:a}} \\
    \subbottom[QMF 04DB1A\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\label{fig319:b}} \\
    \subbottom[QMF 04DB3A\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\label{fig319:c}}
  \end{tabular} \quad
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \subbottom[IQ 02DB2A\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\label{fig319:d}} \\
    \subbottom[IQ 04DBA\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\label{fig319:e}} \\
    \subbottom[IQ 04DB3A\protect\tabstrut]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\label{fig319:f}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Temporary Caption}
  \label{fig319}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\tabstrut` helps with the vertical spacing inside a `tabular` - to obtain the expected `6pt` vertical gap provided by `\abovecaptionskip`.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied this from p48 of the `subfig` package manual, in the FAQ section:

> 6.9
>   “I want my sub-floats to be ordered by column rather than
>   by row, how do I do that?”
>
> The following example shows a schematic for laying out six sub-floats in column order.
>   The only problem with this approach is that, if the floats and their respective captions
>   are not the same height, than the sub-floats will not line up across the page.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
.
.
.
\dots sub-floats (a)--(c) go here.
.
.
.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
.
.
.
\dots sub-floats (e)--(f) go here.
.
.
.
\end{minipage}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually, I want a, b, and c to be one column and other 3 to be another column.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what this set-up does?